# Effect of shorting DC positive pin (Vin+) to Ground (GND) pin on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, power, dc, short-circuit

What effect would shorting a Vin+ pin to GND have? Assuming no DC power has been fed and the board is not connected to power. Would damage the board or has no effect?

Comment: What happens when you hit the gas pedal and the break pedal at the same time in a car that's not running? That's right, it starts flying. The future is now, put on your seat belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the board is not powered, there should be no effect. There will be a short but there will be no (significant) current flowing.

Answer (score 1):

It should cause no problem if the power is not applied. However, if you do this with the power applied, then the low resistance path may cause a large current to flow from Vcc to GND, damaging both pins if no protection is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens cause you don't have any power applied to the board. If you would have a powered up board and short 5V and GND for a short period of time probably nothing would happen. The consumer Developmentboards are wery resistant and have security features to prevent serious damage.